# Identify next row with the same value and create new column pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, iterator

I have the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

# create simple dataset of people
data_pandas = pd.DataFrame({'Order': [1, 1, 1,1,2,2,2],
                             'X': [30,44,30,44,44,30,44],
                             'Y': [46,46,35,45,90,60,60]})
```

I want to create a new column 'Z' with the following logic:
Identify next row with the same 'X' value and create new 'Z' column with the 'Y' value of that row based on the 'Order' column.

The output would look like this

```
data_pandas_result = pd.DataFrame({
        'Order': [1, 1, 1,1,2,2,2],
        'X': [30,44,30,44,44,30,44],
        'Y': [46,46,35,45,90,60,60],
        'Z': [35,45,NA,NA,60,NA,NA]})
```

How do I do this efficiently? I could think of subsetting the dataframe based on order and finding the relevant match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your logic  , `groupby` + `shift`

```
df['Z']=df.groupby(['Order','X']).Y.shift(-1)
df
Out[327]: 
   Order   X   Y        Z
0      1  30  46 35.00000
1      1  44  46 45.00000
2      1  30  35      nan
3      1  44  45      nan
4      2  44  90 60.00000
5      2  30  60      nan
6      2  44  60      nan
```